# Why should the argument of the thread function should be in the heap?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have written a multi-client server in c, using pthread library. when each client try to connect to the server, each client run as a separate thread and handle each client using handle_client function.

And i want to know why I need to declare connfd as a variable in the heap? What problem might occur if it was declared as a local variable?

This is the code to make each thread (in the main() function)

```
int* connfd;
pthread_t thread_id;
int client_sock

while (1)
{
    connfd = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);

    if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL , handle_client , (void*)&client_sock) < 0)
    {
        perror("could not create thread");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here is my hadle_client function.

```
void* handle_client(void* connfd)
{
    /* read a string sent by the client, 
     * print it and then send the string 
     * "Hello from the server" to the client*/

   int sock = *(int*)connfd;
   int read_size;
   char *message , client_message[2000];

   //Send some messages to the client
    message = "Hello from the server\n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

   while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
   {
      //end of string marker
        client_message[read_size] = '\0';

        //Send the message back to client
      puts(client_message);

        //clear the message buffer
        memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    free(connfd);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: notice that in your code, you're passing a pointer to uninitialized automatic `client_sock`; that doesn't look right

Answer (score 1):

For the code to work correctly it is necessary to ensure that:

- the variable containing the connection handle (in your code, `*connfd`) exists for as long as it's required by the `handle_client` thread;
- its value doesn't get overwritten by subsequent iterations of the `while` loop.

It is easier to achieve this with a heap variable, just as you've done in your code.

In general, it is not necessarily wrong to pass the address of a local (automatic, stack-based) variable to a thread function. It just requires a lot more care than using a heap-based variable.

Comment: `In general, it is not necessarily wrong to pass the address of a local` - no in general is wrong, but in most common implementations is sometimes not.  The correct way is to separate data used between threads from the ones used in the thread itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems

- it might be that the lifetime of the variable ends before it is used in the thread. Accessing an object after its lifetime has **undefined behaviour**
- Before C11 no behaviour was specified for accesses to local variables from other threads. As the **behaviour is not defined, it is implicitly undefined**
- C11 says the behaviour of accessing an automatic variable from another thread is **implementation-defined**:

  > An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier static has automatic storage duration, as do some compound literals. The result of attempting to indirectly access an object with automatic storage duration from a thread other than the one with which the object is associated is implementation-defined.

  Did you read the compiler manuals yet?

  GCC says:

  > Such accesses are supported, subject to the same requirements for synchronization for concurrent accesses as for concurrent accesses to any object.
- Even if the accesses are supported, there is a possibility of data race, including the compiler to decide that the value is not needed any more.

**None** of these points apply to objects that are dynamically allocated and not modified after the other thread has been started.

Answer (score 1):

If you use local variable, it will be initialized in main thread's stack. It would be **safe to pass the address** of that variable to respective threads as main thread's stack variables lifetime will obviously be long enough. **But the problem** in doing so is you are updating the fd value everytime in while(1) in the same local variable which will make every thread to use that resulting in undefined behavior.

You will have to allocate new variable **either in heap or stack** for each thread for this reason so that each thread should be able to read correct fd value without any ambiguity.